# UIWebView only shows white screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm working on a sample iOS app that makes use of UIWebView, based on some online tutorials I've found. The sample app compiles, but when I run it on the iOS emulator, the app just displays the text "WebView" before transitioning to a white screen. The app just stays like that afterwards. Is it just taking a long time to load to web page, or is there something wrong with my app?

Contents of ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

Contents of ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    // replacing "[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url]" with "[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]" doesn't seem to help
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Not sure if it will help, but here are the contents of Main.storyboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="6254" systemVersion="14B25" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="6247"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <webView contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="vAN-PO-yTo">
                                <rect key="frame" x="50" y="28" width="600" height="600"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            </webView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: Try adding www. before google.com

Comment: I just tried that, but it's still showing a white screen.

Comment: Are you sure you've properly hooked up the UIWebView in the interface to your view controller?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did. Is there a way to check?

Comment: Click on your web view in the interface and click the right most button on the right-side utilities menu to see if it's connected to your view as a referencing outlet.

Answer (score 0):

Add www to the address. Otherwise it won't work.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    // replacing "[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url]" with "[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]" doesn't seem to help
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```